# Matlab, select "line" range from matrix, not "square"

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
a = [1:1:10]
a = [a+10;a+20;a+30;a+40]

x = 1:1:3
y = 5:1:7

a(x,y)

ans =

    15    16    17
    25    26    27
    35    36    37
```

How can I get a "line" range of elements, not a "square"?
I mean, How can I get the same result as if I call

```
a(x(1), y(1))
a(x(2), y(2))
a(x(3), y(3))
```

but in one operation? (so that x elements will represent x position and y elements will represent y position of selected elements)

Comment: yes, thats it :) ... sorry for duplicate

Comment: That's ok, mistakes happen :)